# Input Char in Doubly Linkedlist C

Tags: c, linked-list, char, malloc, doubly-linked-list

This is my code:

```
struct Node{
    int data;

    char nim[12];

    struct Node *next, *prev;
};
struct Node *head, *tail;

void init(){
   head = NULL;
   tail = NULL;
}

int isEmpty(struct Node *h){
    if(h==NULL)
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}

void addData(char *nimI){

struct Node *baru;
baru = malloc(sizeof *baru);

baru->nim = malloc(12 * sizeof(char));
strcpy(baru->nim, nimI);
baru->next = NULL;
    baru->prev = NULL;
    if(isEmpty(head)==1){
        head=baru;
        tail=baru;
    }else{
        tail->next=baru;
        baru->prev=tail;
        tail = baru;
    }

    printList(head);
}

int main()
{
  char nimI[12];
  printf("NIM          : "); 
  scanf("%[^\n]#", &nimI); 
  fflush(stdin);
  addData(nimI);
}
```

I want to input `char` in my doubly linked list, but it's error.

error :

> assigment to expression with array type (error in baru->nim = malloc(12 * sizeof(char));)

Comment: `char nim[12];` that already declares an array of 12 chars and it will be allocated as part of allocating the struct. Why are you trying to allocate memory for it again? If you really want to allocate that seperately to the struct then change it to `char *nim;`.

Comment: it's work but the output is address of variable not the value @kaylum

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to allocate the memory of an array, so it's worthless to write:

```
baru->nim = malloc(sizeof(char) * 12);
```

This statement is only possible when `char[12]` -> `*char`. Thanks to [@kalyum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66327023/input-char-in-doubly-linkedlist-c/66327051?noredirect=1#comment117260827_66327023), but honestly, I figured out this myself just a few moments ago.

Here's the minimal version of the program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct Node {
  int data;
  char *nim; // Changed num[12] -> *num
};

void addData(char *nimI) {
  struct Node *baru = malloc(sizeof *baru);
  baru->nim = malloc(sizeof(char) * 12); // Now this will work

  strcpy(baru->nim, nimI); // Copying nimI into baru->nim pointer

  printf("%s\n", baru->nim); // Displaying the result
}

int main(void) {
  char nimI[12] = "Hello there";

  // Passing nimI[] (equivalent to *nimI when passed)
  addData(nimI);

  return 0;
}
```

This outputs:

```
Hello there
```

Comment: it's work but the output is address of variable not the value

Comment: @SylviaHelmi Look at the edit. You need to use the `%s` format specifier.